# How should I setup my homepage in django?

Tags: django, django-models, conventions

> I'm not familiar with django
>   conventions at all so if you do
>   provide advice could you be specific

Considering my homepage would contain components of articles:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTLh2.gif]

In Zend, in my IndexController I would create models and populate the view with articles and data. What's a convention/structure I could use for the homepage view ( should I create a separate directory for home, dump a view.html file in it? or do I create a sub-application? ), how would you set your django structure up to accommodate this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic component of a Django project is the **application**. Each app contains **models**, **views**, **templates**, **template tags**, and **filters** relevant to its portion of the project. The index view imports/uses resources from other apps to get its work done. Think of the homepage as parts brought into a whole, and put each independent part in its own application.

Comment: Well, can you demonstrate using the content in the image at least how you should go about personally setting up the homepage? At least so I can get an idea somewhat.

Comment: Have an `articles` app that has the model for articles, as well as a manager and templates for specific types of articles, and then have a `frontpage` app that has the main template that includes the article templates for display.